# Illegal syntax error

Tags: loops, syntax-error, lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun copy (l)                                                                                                                         
  (let ((lst (list)))                                                                                                                   
    (loop for i in l                                                                                                                    
          (if (not (null i))                                                                                                   
              (push i (cdr (last lst))))))                                                                                     
  lst)
```

I'm having an error which I don't understand.

This function is supposed to copy the elements of a list to a new list.
The error apoints to illegal syntax inside the `LOOP` statement.

Comment: Next time, please do not post an image, but a text.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing essentially boils down to the following piece of modern poetry:

```
(defun remove-nil (list) (remove nil list))
```

Your code is written as-if it was Scheme, which is quite different from Common lisp. In your case, this even makes your code errorneous. Details follow:

1. The function is badly named, at first sight it looks like you only want to perform a copy but you are also filtering it.
2. You can write `list`, there is no need to drop vowels.
3. You don't need to write `(list)` to build an empty list, simply declaring the auxiliary variable without a binding will initialize it to `nil`. If you want, you can explicitely bind your variable to `nil` to notify readers that you are doing this on purpose, but I rarely see it.
4. `Let` is not like Scheme's `define`, `lst` is not bound anymore when you escape the `let`. You should have this instead:

   ```
   (let ((lst ...))
      ...
     lst)
   ```
5. `(not (null x))` is the Scheme way of dealing with empty lists. In Common Lisp, you can write `(when x ...)`.
6. The `loop` macro allows two different forms, a simple one which looks like a  `progn` (i.e. a list of forms) and another one where you use `loop` keywords (collect, sum, repeat, ...): your `(if ...)` would need to have a `do` before it. But you could also use the `when` loop keyword. This is what I would suggest to do if you want to use a loop:

   ```
   (defun remove-nil (list)
     (loop for e in list when e collect e))
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I've changed the code to : (defun copy(l)
   (setf lst
(loop for i in l 
   when i
   collect i
  ) 
 )
 lst
)

Comment: @JoãoCosta That's better, but `setf` is modifying `lst` which is not declared in this context (I don't think you have a `defvar`, do you?). Your system will probably define a global variable name `lst` to hold the temporary value, which is bad style. Let is what you need.

Comment: @JoãoCosta Although in this specific case, you might as well just let the value of the loop form be the return value of the function, actually binding it (via let, or othewise) is only useful if you need to hold on to it for further manipulations before returning.